# current_timestamp y default existe en mongoDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

tengo un modelo en mysql donde cada update o insert genera una current_timestamp, es para seguridad de la data. por otro lado cada insert inicia con el campo estado en 1.
ahora como  puedo usar esa logica pero en mongoDB. me lei el manual por arriba y no vi nada parecido.

gracias

Comment: ¿Encontraste esto en la [documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)?

Comment: si lo lei. pero todavia no termine de interpretarlo. cada insert de un doc podria poner new Date() pero mi idea es que se inserte automatico como en sql

Comment: gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

En MongoDB, el equivalente de NOW() de MySQL es new Date(). Esta función devuelve un objeto Date que representa la fecha y hora actuales.

Por ejemplo, para obtener la fecha y hora actuales en MongoDB, podemos usar el siguiente código:

```
const now = new Date();

console.log(now);
```

Esto imprimirá el siguiente resultado:

```
2023-08-31T17:01:31.000Z
```

También podemos usar la función now para obtener la fecha y hora actuales en una consulta MongoDB. Por ejemplo, para encontrar todos los documentos en una colección que fueron creados antes de la fecha actual, podemos usar el siguiente código:

```
db.collection.find({
  createdAt: { $lt: new Date() }
});
```

Este código devolverá todos los documentos en la colección en los que el campo createdAt es anterior a la fecha y hora actuales.

En versiones anteriores a MongoDB 4.2, no había una función equivalente a NOW(). Para obtener la fecha y hora actuales, se podía usar la función ISODate(), que devuelve una cadena en formato ISO 8601. Sin embargo, esta función no es tan eficiente como new Date().

Comment: eso lo vi. el tema es que se carga en un insert o update pero no de manera automatica. tendria que hacer un $set del campo.

Comment: gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

no se permite en MongoDB el uso de Dafault en sus JSONSchemas. solo carga de datos posterior a la creaccion del schema y su collection

Comment: eh? esto que quiere decir?

Comment: que no podes poner un valor por defecto en un campo en mongodb

Comment: o sea, tu respuesta a tu pregunta es no se puede... eso queres decir???